# Setting hidden field value from path parametrs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

i'm stacked. I'm creating application where user can create a blog, where he can put any posts. So associatins are:

blog :has many posts and posts :belongs to blog. But also blog is associated to user same way. (blogs are nested for users). 
The show page of post has a link:

```
= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(blog_id: blog.id)
```

Where i send blog_id to get in from hidden form in post. It works fine(http address:)

```
http://localhost:3000/posts/1/edit?blog_id=1
```

But when i press to the show button of post(after creating) rails trying to find the blog with post id.
Adress:

> http://localhost:3000/posts/2

And error: ***Couldn't find Blog with 'id'=2***
In line:

```
= link_to 'Edit', edit_post_path(blog_id: blog.id)
```

The problem is if I delete parameters of path i can not set it in the hidden form(blog_id) in edit. How should I solve it?

UPD:
Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  root to: "pages#index"
  get "users/profile" => "user_blogs#index", :as => "user_root"
  devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "users/registrations" }
  resources :users do
    resources :blogs
  end
  resources :posts do
    resources :comments
  end
end
```

Post controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html

  before_action :authenticate_user!

  expose :blog
  expose :post

  def show
  end

  def new
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    post.user = current_user
    post.save
    respond_with post, location: user_blog_path(post.blog.user, post.blog)
  end

  def update
    post.update(post_params)
    respond_with post, location: user_blog_path(post.blog.user, post.blog)
  end

  def destroy
    post.destroy
    respond_with post, location: user_blog_path(post.blog.user, post.blog)
  end

  private

  def post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title, :content, :user_id, :blog_id)
  end
end
```

Comment: can you add your routes and controller action?

Comment: @fedetaglia see update